# Find client Id of control in a user control inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

So...I'm trying to find the client ID of a control (a hidden input field) which is part of a user control which is bound dynamically to a Grid view 'Item template'.
I was trying to do the following in the "RowDataBound" event and doesn't seem to work.

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (ShowSelectColumn)
        {

            HiddenField MfrHiddenField =  (e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("MfrNumHiddenfield")) as HiddenField;
}
```

wherein "MfrNumHiddenfield" is the ID of the hidden input field. e.row.cells[2] is the cell number of the column to which the 'user control' is bound to...

below is how the user control gets added to the gridview:

```
    grid.Columns.Add(CreateTemplateField(
            path + "ManufacturerHeader.ascx",
            path + "ManufacturerCell.ascx"));
```

Is anything wrong with what i am trying to do? please help

Comment: Are you trying to find the ID of a control or are you trying to get the control from the ID?  Because it seems like you already know the ID?

Comment: I need to know the "client ID" of the control for what i am doing. because it is wrapped in a "masterpage-Gridview-column-usercontrol" it is getting difficult for me to find the control using the ID of the control. I was trying to find the control inside of the bound column at bind time using the "FindControl" method.

Comment: From where are you trying to get this value?  The master page or the page?

Comment: I'm trying to get this value on the page. Basically the code that is trying to do this is the code behind for the Gridview, and it is trying to do so at the time a datarow is bound to the grid.(as you might see from the code pasted in my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually need to look in the cell. `e.Row.FindControl("MfrNumHiddenfield")` should be enough.

Since you are looking for a control in a custom control, you could try:

```
e.Row.FindControl("manufacturerCellControl").FindControl("MfrNumHiddenfield")
```

I have never tried it, but it seems plausible.

A better option would be to expose a property from the `ManufacturerCell` control to make the change you want. This would keep clients of the control from needing to understand the inner workings. Just create a property, and write the code in the `get` and `set` methods.

Comment: The `HiddenField` is inside the `Manufacturer...` control?

Comment: I've never done it, but since the `ManufacturerCell` probably introduces its own `NamingContainer`, you could first find the `ManufacturerCell` in the row, then find the `HiddenField` in the control. I have updated my answer to propose this and explain what I have done in my own controls.

Comment: I eventually ended up doing this. : _mfrCellClientIDPrefix = e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0].ClientID;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though...it was useful